# ext4fuse as non-root on FreeBSD10

Tags: linux, permissions, freebsd, root, fuse

I have 2 operating systems on my computer, a Arch Linux on a 100GB ext4 partition, a FreeBSD on a 250GB partition and all my data on 2 2TB separated ext4 disks.

I wan't to access the files from this two disks using my FreeBSD, i search on the web and the best result that i've found is to use ext4fuse, i tryed to mount my disks using `ext4fuse /device /folder`, it works but i can't read the content with my normal user, the permissions to read is only for root user:

```
[root@******* /usr/home/********/Arch Linux]# ls -lha
total 72
dr-xr-xr-x    4 root   wheel   4.0K Aug 28 19:37 .
drwxr-xr-x   29 *****  *****   1.0K Feb 20 15:43 ..
dr-x------  108 1000   100      12K Feb 20 06:24 *********
dr-x------    2 root   wheel    16K Aug 28 16:18 lost+found
```

Since i can't find any documentation about ext4fuse and it mounted only at read-only, i can't do anything else.

If at least i could give permission to the wheel group to read the file, i could read-it with my normal user, since only root has permissions on this device, i cannot even cd to this folder with my normal user.

`/usr/home/*******/Arch Linux` is my 2TB partition with my data mounted using ext4fuse.

Answer (score 1):

According to [its github page](https://github.com/gerard/ext4fuse), ext4fuse is *read-only*:

> This is a read-only implementation of ext4 for FUSE.

This is implemented in [fuse-main.c](https://github.com/gerard/ext4fuse/blob/master/fuse-main.c), by not providing functions for any operation that can change the filesystem (the full list of possible operations is [here](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/doxygen/structfuse__operations.html));

```
static struct fuse_operations e4f_ops = {
    .getattr = op_getattr,
    .readdir = op_readdir,
    .open = op_open,
    .read = op_read,
    .readlink = op_readlink,
    .init = op_init,
};
```

And in [op_getattr.c](https://github.com/gerard/ext4fuse/blob/master/op_getattr.c), by removing all write bits from permissions;

```
stbuf->st_mode = inode.i_mode & ~0222;
```

But it doesn't remove all group bits.

This means that you cannot change *anything* on the `ext4` filesystem from FreeBSD. And the lack of group permissions comes from the `ext4` filesystem itself. So you will have to add group permissions to the files when you boot into Arch Linux.